# WP_Query - Inherit meta_query and tax_query value from associated post if value doesn't exists or it's empty

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have two custom post types: **venue** and **event**.

Lets say that both post types have the **_location** meta key (custom field) and both of them also have **music-genre** taxonomy.

Event also has **_association** meta key which contains ID of the associated venue.

Now Querying events by mentioned taxonomy and meta field is very easily done like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'tax_query' => [
    [
      'taxonomy' => 'music-genre',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => ['house', 'jazz', 'rock']
    ]
  ],
  'meta_query' => [
    [
      'key' => '_location',
      'value' => ['Miami', 'Ibiza', 'Zrce'],
      'compare' => 'IN'
    ]
  ]
]);

$posts = $query->posts;
```

But I want to also get events with empty '_location' field IF his parent/associated post (ID stored under _association meta key) has expected value. Same thing for taxonomies - Music Genre in this example. If event doesn't have associated "Jazz" music genre, but his associated post has it then it should be returned by WP_Query.

So basically I want to inherit meta values and taxonomies from associated post if they doesn't exists or are empty.

I hope you can understand what I want to achieve well... otherwise please ask for further explanation.

In case anyone is wondering im using [Carbon Fields](https://carbonfields.net/) library for custom fields.

Also my project is much more complicated, but everything was simplified for this question, so performance matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand... are you looking for this `'hide_empty' => false`?